# Recommended way to deploy ppp/pppoe in Ubuntu 20.04 server ? netplan ? ifupdown?

Tags: 20.04, netplan, pppoe, ppp

What's the recommended way to deploy PPP/PPPoE in 20.04 ? Netplan doesn't seem to support that; Is ifupdown still the way forward even though it's going away ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using ifupdown is likely the best way to continue to deploy PPP connections that you want to start on boot on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issue in ubuntu. I just updated to 20.10 so not sure if this will work on 20.04 or not but you can give it a try.

From terminal run this command

```
nm-connection-editor -s
```

This should pop a utility using which you should be able to add pppoe or any other type of connection easily.